# My simple while loop hangs my computer on larger inputs

Tags: python, while-loop

This is my response to a HackerRank challenge

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/repeated-string

```
def repeatedString(s, n):
   string = ''
   count = 0

   while len(string) < n:
      for letter in s:
         if len(string) != n:
            string += letter
            if letter == 'a':
               count += 1
   return count

print(repeatedString('aba', 10))
>> 7 # works!
```

's' is a string input eg. 'abc', which theoretically repeats forever. 'n' is the number of characters I need to use of that infinite string, eg. 'abcabcabca' if n = 10

I then need to find the number of occurrences of 'a', my function works fine on small integers but for the test case in the question, they use 1000000000000 and everything times-out, even on my laptop.

Is there a more efficient and less resource intensive way of doing this?

Comment: Define the length of the string s as s.len. The worst runtime should be bounded by s.len and *not n*. In other words you do not need to actually build the n length string to make inferences about the histogram of characters at any point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do some math instead of looping:

```
def repeatedString(s, n):
   q, r = divmod(n, len(s))
   return s.count('a') * q + s[:r].count('a')
```

The value of `n` doesn't matter for this solution. `repeatedString('abca', 100000000000000000000000)` runs only 30% slower than `repeatedString('abca', 10)`.

Comment: If I understand this right... if I had ('aba', 10), what you're saying in the return, is we know how many times 'a' appears in 's' because it's a given, and you use divmod() to find how many time the length of 's' goes in to 'n', so therefore you know it's the occurrences of 'a' in 's' * q plus the occurrences (if any) in the left over, 'r'.